# MySQL Regex for excluding string

Tags: mysql, regex

Im trying to perform a regex match in mysql to match a string when part of the string is not present. i.e

```
src="/images/(?legacy)
```

if the string `src="/images/` is present but the string `legacy` is not.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL regexen do not support negative lookaheads, so I think your best bet would be to use two *or* to use `LIKE`

```
string LIKE '%src="/images/%'
AND string NOT LIKE '%src="/images/legacy%'
```

Note that this query would be inefficient (as it would be using regexen).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you're asking, but MySQL regexes do not support negative lookahead and AFAIK mysql regexes dont use the index.

So i think you may be over thinking it, as the regex would be shorter in writing (if it could work, which it cant) but traditional LIKE is faster.

I suggest you simply use:

```
WHERE (
   content LIKE '%src="/images/%' 
   AND 
   content NOT LIKE '%src="/images/legacy%'
)
```

Comment: Oh. @Explosion Pills posted while is was writing ;).. But my point stands. If you have indexes on the content, LIKE is MUCH faster!